# Random generation algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, random

Suppose you need to generate a random permutation of the first N integers. For example, {4, 3, 1, 5, 2} and {3, 1, 4, 2, 5} are legal permutations, but {5, 4, 1, 2, 1} is not, because one number (1) is duplicated and another (3) is missing. This routine is often used in simulation of algorithms. We assume the existence of a random number generator, RandInt(i,j), that generates between i and j with equal probability. Here is the algorithm:

Fill the array A from A[0] to A[N-1] as follows: To fill A[i], generate random numbers until you get one that is not already in A[0], A[1],…, A[i-1].

Implement this algorithm in C++ and find the complexity. This is my code:

```
int a;
bool b = false;
A[0] = RandInt(1,n);
for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {
do {
  b = false;
  a = RandInt(1,n);
  for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
     if(A[j] == a)
        b = true;
} while(b);
A[i] = a;
}
```

Is this code correct? And how can I find the complexity of the algorithm? Since, RandInt(i,j) generates random numbers, I don't know how many times the do while loop will be repeated.

Comment: If the sequence is less than about 1,000,000,000 values: fill an array with the values in sequence and use pairs of random numbers to shuffle the array by swapping values.  Do at least as many swaps as the size of the array.  To get working code reviewed please post on __Code Review__: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RichardCritten Better approach would be [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) or `std::shuffle`, which guarantee uniform distribution, but OP is stuck with a technique he was told to use anyway.

Comment: `shuffle` a vector fed by `iota`.

Comment: Generate random numbers and add then to a `std::set`, which will automatically eliminate duplicates.  Stop adding when the size of the `set` reaches the desired value.  For the complexity you need to look at the probability of picking an already picked number as the size of the `set` increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm will produce correct results, selecting a permutation uniformly at random from all possible permutations.

The running time is not bounded above by any deterministic function since, as you point out, it could run literally forever. In the best case, this algorithm runs in O(n^2) and selects a random permutation without having to repeat any selection. On average, you'd expect to have to try n/n=1 time to get the first unique random, n/(n-1) times to get the second, and so on down to an expected value of n/1=n times to get the last one. Adding those together gives you n*H(n), where H(n) is the nth harmonic number. It turns out H(N) is Theta(log n) so this algorithm is O(n^2 log n) in the average case.

There is a better way to do what you're trying to do: you can start with any permutation and shuffle it into another one using an algorithm that is O(n) in the worst case. The algorithm is the Fisher-Yates algorithm and works as follows:

```
FisherYates(array[1...n])
1. if n == 1 then return
2. r = random(2, n)
3. temp = array[1]
4. array[1] = array[r]
5. array[r] = temp
6. FisherYates(array[2...n])
```

This is a recursive formulation but an iterative one is straightforward. It calls `random` exactly `n` times, where `n` is the size of the array at the topmost invocation.

Comment: But don't we have 1+2+3+...+n-1+n searches in the second for loop in the best case? Isn't it O(n^2)?

Comment: @OlsionHysa You know what, you're right. I missed that. That will add a term `n` to each of the complexities given: best and average case. So these are actually O(n^2) for the best case and O(n^2 log n) for the average case. My apologies.